# Spreading out Centered Navigation Bar in HTML

Tags: html, css

[Banners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV1TV.jpg)
I am looking to "spread out" my centered banner in HTML. I was able to actually spread out the text, but I want to make the links from the banner bigger, as they are currently on the size of my text. If any clarification is needed, please let me know.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0F5AEA;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #F2F2F2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #BBEAFA;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #6F16A5;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Top Navigation Example</h2>
  <p>Some content..</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide this as a snippet so we can see a live version of your project? I feel like a `flex-grow:1` on your links would do but I'm not sure what you currently have, and what you'd like to see… Additionally, you should be using semantic HTML tags like `<nav>` to define your content.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen ; I have added the image of the banners! The purple shows the size of the "link" and I would like to make the actual link larger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give it a `max-width:25%` and force `width: 100%`. Also you do not need `float` since you're using `flex`.

```
.topnav a {
  max-width: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #F2F2F2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

[Check it live on Codepen here](https://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/BaNxOxx).

Comment: While this approach works for 4 elements, using `flex` or `flex-grow` is much more... _flexible_

Comment: You're right, it is! No pun intended there, right...?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `flex-grow: 1` to the navigation links. If you want all of them to be the same width, you can use `flex: 1` which does the same as a combination of `flex-grow: 1` and `flex-basis: 0`.

```
.topnav a {
  flex-grow: 1;  // or flex: 1;
  float: left;  // this does not have effect on flex items by the way
  color: #F2F2F2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

If you want to learn more, there is no need to repeat already well documented:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis

Here is one of your options:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0F5AEA;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.topnav a {
  flex: 1;
  float: left;
  color: #F2F2F2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #BBEAFA;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #6F16A5;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Top Navigation Example</h2>
  <p>Some content..</p>
</div>
```